# how to add multiple custom views into UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am developing an app in which I need following functionality.

1. Download multiple image files from server.
2. Display it into grid format.

To fullfil above requirement,

I made custom view with .xib file. and added it into scrollview.

But can't get any idea on how to download images asynchronously and display it at proper place.

My code for adding custom view in grid style is here.

```
-(void)LazyLoading_display_Objects_in_grid_style
{

    for(int i=0; i<[imageListingArray count] ; i++)
    {
        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:nil options:nil];
        MyView *myView = (MyView *)[arr objectAtIndex:0];
        myView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
myView.imgPhoto setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        myView.imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[imageListingArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]];
 [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        if(myView.imgPhoto.image == nil)
            [myView.actLoading startAnimating];

        [myView.imgPhoto setTag:1000+i];

        [myView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
        myView.tag = 100+i;

        [self.imageListingScrollView addSubview:myView];

        if(current_no_of_object_in_row !=noOfObjectInColumn)
        {
            x =x + width + 8 ;
            current_no_of_object_in_row ++;
        }
        else
        {
            current_no_of_object_in_row =1;
            x = 5;
            y = y+ height + 8 ;
        }
        scrollView_Height = y;
    }
int temp = [imageListingArray count]%noOfObjectInColumn;

    if(temp>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"No modulus");
        y = y + height+ 10;
    }
    scrollView_Height = y;
    NSLog(@"Scroll Height : %d",scrollView_Height);
    [self.imageListingScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(308, scrollView_Height+ 5)];
}
```

Comment: I have a very nice API which you can use to cache the image. Please give me your email address i'll forward it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating multiple views you can go for UITableView. It'll work as both UIScrollViews and Grid display. This links might help you :

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/
http://davidgolightly.blogspot.in/2009/02/asynchronous-image-caching-with-iphone.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a UITableView instance and rotate it like:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0f);    
table.transform = transform;
```

U may also have to rotate the cells inside the UITableView likewise in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0f);
  cell.transform = transform;
}
```

If take a UIScrollView as such then u have to handle memory may check out [myquestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967718/reusing-3-views-on-uiscrollviews-paging)

Comment: Hi Ishank, thanks for your answer. I have used JMCaching library for download images. Into it first time, it will download images and after it every time it will get from cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use AsyncImageView class. It's extension for UIImage which allows async download image from direct URL. I uses similar extension in a lot of projects. You have just to call method

```
- (void)loadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)URL;
```

and when data will be retrieved image will appear in this view.
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

And grid you can make by using UICollectionView class if you make project for iOS 6+ of UITableView for all iOS'es.
If you'll use UITableView, you can make custom cells with two AsyncImageView objects in left and right sides.