# Which is best if I wanted Page based design?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, lazy-loading, uipageviewcontroller

Which one is good to use  for a page based design, `Pageviewcontroller` or `UIScrollview` with paging.

Which will consume less memory? I have done it via `UIScrollview`; but it's consuming very huge memory. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is opinion based. However, you should consider implementing _reuse_ of subviews to improve performance and memory efficiency.

Comment: How can reuseview & memory efiiciencyin scrollview

Comment: The concept is similar to `UITableView` cell reuse. Check if you can implement required UI using `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`. If not then look into implementing `UIScrollView` reuse. Check out [Advanced ScrollView Techniques](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/index.php) WWDC 2011 video.

Answer (score 1):

Using `UIScrollView` for the application is not a handy task. For iOS 6, you should use `UIPageViewController`. But for iOS 5, `UIPageViewController` is not be good as it only provides scrolling for the page transition.

You may reuse the `UIScrollView` views then,

Many examples are there in SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13127131/1790571)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say which is "best" - it depends on what makes sense for your app. Which ever approach you choose you can minimise memory consumption by "lazy loading" content into the scroll view when it is needed.  For example, if you were displaying pages of images and the images are stored as files in your app then you should only add the current image and the image either side of the current image.  As you scroll you can load and add the next image and release.

Here is a tutorial that shows this approach with UIScrollView- [Multiple virtual pages in a UIScrollView with just 2 child views](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html)

UIPageViewController makes it a bit simpler by adopting a dataSource pattern, so you can concentrate on responding to data requests and not have to worry about manipulating the views.